# iBeacon monitoring/ranging after phone restarts

Tags: ios, core-location, ibeacon

After rebooting my phone, my app stops getting CoreLocation delegate callbacks, is it an expected behavior? I think I remember reading that you could still get callbacks. If so, is there anywhere in the documentation saying if its possible or not?

Comment: can you say which version of iOS you are on? iOS 7 or iOS 7.1? monitoring should work after restart with iOS 7.1. iBeacon ranging only work when the application is active (displayed on screen).

Comment: Oh yeah forgot to mention it, 7.1

Answer (score 5):

This is not normal.  An app is supposed to get callbacks to CoreLocation's methods after your phone reboots, and I have built this feature into multiple apps and verified it works.

Three things make this hard to test, so be sure you are taking these into account:

1. After an iOS device reboots, it does not perform bluetooth scans to look for iBeacons right away.   I do not know the exact timing, but it may take a minute or more.
2. Even after the above time passes, scans for iBeacons are not happening continually when your app is not ranging for iBeacons in the foreground.  Make sure you wait up to 15 minutes (16 minutes after reboot) before you declare that you aren't getting background notifications.
3. In a typical setup, you won't see your logging statements after a reboot.  So it is quite possible you are getting callbacks but there is nothing visible happening as a result.  Make sure you do something in your callback for testing, like an unconditional local notification, so you know for sure whether you are getting the callbacks or not.

Comment: Oh hey David, thanks for always taking time to answer beacons related questions ... I have local notifications on beacon ranging and waited for more than 20 minutes and still no notifications ... I'm also thrilled about this behavior and don't know what to do or test

Comment: Wait... you say you "have local notifications on beacon ranging".  Did you mean to say *monitoring*?  You generally cannot get ranging callbacks in the background at all, even if you don't do a reboot.  You can only get monitoring callbacks.

Comment: As in iOS 7.1 now you can get ranging callbacks in the background and now running at all as I understand ... And yeah, I have notifications all over CoreLocation delegate methods (didDetermineState:, didEnterRegion: and didExitRegion:)

Comment: Can you post the code that shows:  (1) how you set up monitoring in CoreLocation, (2) the callback method that displays the local notification.

Comment: @davidgyoung : This is again related to monitoring beacon after reboot. So thought of commenting here itself instead if starting new thread. 1.Is it mandate to used UIBackgroundModes - location and Device capabilities - location-services in info.plist for receiving beacon monitoring notification (enter/exit region) after reboot? 2.I am inside the beacon region while rebooting the device.I am doing any boundary crossing.Will i be getting enter region notification again, once i reboot my phone?

Comment: No background modes are necessary.  When rebooting, you are not guaranteed to get events telling you are still in the region.  But CoreLocation sometimes sends duplicate enter events, even when not across a reboot, so your code should allow for this.